Are json with double quotes treated differently in Presto?
Using Presto SQL, the original format of the column appears like this "{\"ORDERS (completed)\": 1000.00, \"ORDERS (failed) USD\": 3000.00}" and I am trying to extract the key and value by parsing and casting as map (varchar, double) and then unnesting
UNNEST(
    CAST(JSON_PARSE(json) as MAP<VARCHAR, DOUBLE>)
) x(key, value)

When I use json_parse, the forward slashes and quotes disappear, but I receive an error (Expected a json object) when trying to cast as map<varchar, double>
{"ORDERS (filled)": 1000.00, "ORDERS (succeeded) USD": 3000.00}
I've also tried casting as json, but received a similar error
"{\"ORDERS (completed) USD\": 1000.0}" "\"{\\\"ORDERS (failed) USD\\\": 3000.0}\""

Your JSON is a string that contains encoded JSON (basically it is a double-encoded JSON), so parsing it one time will not do the trick. The more correct approach would be to double parse it:
with dataset(col) as (
    values ('"{\"ORDERS (completed)\": 1000.00, \"ORDERS (failed) USD\": 3000.00}"')
)

select cast(
           json_parse(
               json_extract_scalar(
                   json_parse(col), '$')) as map(varchar, double))
from dataset;

Which gives the following output:
                          _col0                          
---------------------------------------------------------
 {ORDERS (failed) USD=3000.0, ORDERS (completed)=1000.0} 


this worked and definitely a better solution than what i did, thanks so much!

The solution to my problem:
cast(json_parse(replace(substr(col, 2, length(col) - 2), '\', '')) as map<varchar, double>)

We want to be careful to not remove all of the double quotes for json_parse to work, just need the double quotes surrounding the json string. So we use substr(col, 2, length(col) - 2) to get the string inside of the quotes. We will need to replace the forward slashes with '' for json_parse to convert to json. Then we can use json_parse and cast as map<type, type> as usual.
